# Update intervals of VPN client code

Tags: vpn, updates

I recently had to find a VPN client to connect to a preconfigured Cisco IPSec VPN. Of course there's Cisco's own client implementation [AnyConnect](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client-v4-x/model.html), but I wanted to stick with a free alternative if possible. (**Edit:** I also just read that [AnyConnect *doesn't* support IPSec in the first place](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/99819/160472).) Said and done I found a couple of applications, but it appears they're all rather old:

- For Windows there's mostly the famous [Shrewsoft client](https://www.shrew.net/download/vpn). Its most recent release 2.2.2 dates back to July 1st, 2013.
- On Linux *vpnc* is probably the most widely known implementation. It seems like its [original maintainers abandoned it](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/) after releasing version 0.5.3 on November 19th, 2008. Anyways, that version is still being taken care of by different communities, e.g. [Debian most recently patched it to 0.5.3r550-3](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/v/vpnc/vpnc_0.5.3r550-3_changelog) on November 23rd, 2016.
- As a system-independent candidate let's add [OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/download.html). Its most recent release is from December 13th, 2016.

Now for a widely used and security critical network application, I find it likely that vulnerabilities are found regularly and that security fixes are published every so often. However, I also realise that by now all these applications have had plenty of time to go through a lot of hardening. So here's my question:

*How much of an issue is long update intervals for VPN clients like the ones mentioned above?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrewsoft hasn't been updated in 6 years either, but from your list if you look at OpenConnect CVEs [there are a few listed over the years](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-11147/product_id-20069/Infradead-Openconnect.html).

There are also various issues listed in [Github](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect/issues).  The issues normally centre around DoS for the client from certain responses, or crashes/bugs in the program when making a request.  If your question was whether the encryption offered by a VPN is compromised in older programs, since they use [well-defined](https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/rfc/RFC4307EN.html) algorithms that's probably not an issue.  If your question is whether they can be used securely on a system without issue, that's probably not the case since they [mostly](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/nonroot.html) require root access to create a network interface.

Running any software that is not regularly updated or well maintained increases the number of vectors available for a malicious actor for attack however, so wherever possible using software that is no longer updated should be avoided.  Merely by installing them [an issue might be created](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2010-3361/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think that you are making a very good point here, namely that securing communication and securing the communicating systems are two different concerns. That also lines up with well established best practices: Use VPNs to secure communication, but avoid installing extra software to secure systems. When viewed this way my question boils down to weighing up those two concerns.